# Focus element showing unexpected rectangle in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to get back focus on a content control when sub-menu is closed, but an unexpected rectangle is showing in first time. Once I click on any empty space or menu item, it's gone. what's the problem

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" >
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFDDDDDD"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=placeholder}"/>
    <!--TargetName="placeholder"-->
</Trigger>
```

[image]

Comment: setting `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` on your element might help. default FocusVisualStyle is dotted rectangle

Comment: Thanks @Ash, it saves my life ! If you post as answer, i will accept gently :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

control has focus and gray dotted rectangle is its `FocusVisualStyle`. to remove it set `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"`

Answer (score 0):

you can set `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` or set `IsFocusable = False`

Comment: Please provide some information why this answer solves the problem.